# How can I make it return 'Not Found User' when the user was deleted?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have this in my `models/comment.rb`
However it returns error when the user was deleted.
How can I make it return 'Not Found User' when the user was deleted?

**models/comment.rb**

```
  def self.last_comment_nickname
    order("id").last.user.profile.nickname
  end
```

Comment: Check to see if the user exists first? Also, if this is being iterated over in the view, check to see if your DB is getting slammed on large pages.

Comment: @DaveNewton Sorry about lack of information. I use the gem called `acts_as_paranoid` which enables logical deletion.  The user is deleted by this logical deletion. The user is supposed to be deleted here.

Comment: all I want to do is getting 'Not Found User' when the user was nil

Comment: Check to see if the user is nil first?

Comment: @DaveNewton Yes, How can I add code to this? please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [andand gem](http://andand.rubyforge.org/):

```
def self.last_comment_nickname
  order("id").last.user.andand.profile.andand.nickname || "Not Found User"
end
```

Or just write code; honestly if you're not sure how to check a value for null I'm afraid just telling you would do more harm than good in the long run.

Although I might delegate profile methods to the user.

Answer (score 1):

```
def self.last_comment_nickname
  user = order("id").last.user
  user.present? ? user.profile.nickname : "Not Found User"
end
```

Comment: Thanks! Can I write like this too?  `def self.last_comment_nickname        return order("id").last.user.profile.nickname if order("id").last.user     return ""       end`